# Extract XY extent from WKT string

Tags: python, gdal, wkt

Using python, how can I extract the XY extent of a WKT polygon? I need it in gdal compatible format like: minx miny maxx maxy

So for example below, I'd need to convert `wkt` to be `wkt_extent`:

```
wkt = "Polygon ((366247 156971, 366247 174054, 383331 174054, 383331 156971, 366247 156971))"
# need xy bounding box coordinates of wkt, as shown below
wkt_extent = "366247 156971 383331 174054"
```

Please keep in mind that the wkt is not always a rectangle/square and is not always 'drawn' in a clockwise direction like the example wkt shown here.

SRID here is 27700 and units are in meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your WKT is passed as a string:

```
def parse_geometry(geometry):
    regex = r'[0-9-\.]+'
    parsed_geom = re.findall(regex, geometry)
    parsed_geom = [float(i) for i in parsed_geom]
    return max(parsed_geom[::2]), min(parsed_geom[::2]), max(parsed_geom[1::2]), min(parsed_geom[1::2])
```

Comment: Don't you need a float() in there somewhere?

Comment: yeah if you want the outputs as floats then you do

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a dependency on GDAL/OGR, you can use this:

```
geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
extent = geom.GetEnvelope()
```

The extent will be a tuple: `(366247.0, 383331.0, 156971.0, 174054.0)`

Having the extra dependency is of course a downside, but OGR does handle the parsing/validation for you.